# Angular Create custom list of filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm completely new to angular so forgive my question.
I'm trying to create a list of filters with the user input. Here's a plunker of what i'm trying to do.
http://plnkr.co/edit/asrZJj2HFJCnmmqJLlgt?p=preview

I understand that my condition for my ng-repeat should be something like that:

```
ng-repeat="filter in filters | filter: filters"
```

and inside my **filters** something like that to work

```
ng-repeat="...| filter:{dev:java, happy:true}"
```

So can i do it in the way i'm trying to do or i have to create a filter module?

Comment: Are you trying to filter the data ?

Comment: yes i'm exactely trying to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to use simple object for filters instead of array, where filter name would be a property key. In this case you would render filters like this:

```
<span class="btn btn-success" ng-repeat="(name, value) in filters">
    <strong>{{name}} : {{value}}</strong>
</span>
```

and populate them in controller like this:

```
$scope.createFilter = function(name, value) {
    $scope.filters[name] = value;
    $scope.cleanInput();
};
```

With this setup it's very easy to apply filters to the table data:

```
ng-repeat="user in users | filter:filters"
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Hp8EPpvHv8vklSiFOG6U?p=info

Comment: I was also wondering to create a filter when the user click on a row but this time only with the user name, have you an idea to do it in the same way? and by the way thanks again man!

Comment: You can use ngClick on `tr`. Check this demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/U13deGvSfdqJo0JFsLC4?p=preview

Comment: Thank you a lot, so easy with your solution ;)